# Android request window feature

Tags: android, window

in my application on a single activity screen i want to request following two window features :

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
```

Both are working when added one at a time but they are not working when i add both of them together.

Please suggest how we can do it in android ?

**EDIT**
 MY ACTIVITY CODE

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v("TAG", "After super.onCreate()");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); 
        Log.v("TAG", "after Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS");
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        Log.v("TAG", "after Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON");
        setContentView(R.layout.categotylist);
        Log.v("TAG", "after setContentView");
        lists = new ArrayList<String>();
\\some more code
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
06-02 13:02:37.813: D/Prototype(421): ViewPagerActivityActivity : LOADING CATEGORY
06-02 13:02:38.092: D/dalvikvm(421): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 7300 objects / 470264 bytes in 59ms
06-02 13:02:38.112: I/global(421): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
06-02 13:02:38.982: V/TAG(421): After super.onCreate()
06-02 13:02:38.982: V/TAG(421): after Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS
06-02 13:02:38.992: V/TAG(421): after Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON
06-02 13:02:39.172: V/TAG(421): after setContentView
```

Comment: `but they are not working? then what happens and can you tell me what you want using both`

Comment: only this `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); ` works

Comment: yes @raveN : this can be done by using this `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`//add whatever flags you want